# Django. Разграничить права пользователей по клиентам

Tags: python, django, rules

Имеем:

Django модель список клиентов (таблица в БД со списком клиентов и другой различной информацией)

Что требуется:

Предоставлять пользователям Django доступ к информации по определённому клиенту\клиентам (права на клиентов мы можем изменять)
т.е что бы при авторизации пользователя отображался список клиентов к информации о которых у пользователя есть доступ.

Прошу описать схему как это можно реализовать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То что вам нужно называется ACL - access control list.

В django я бы делал так. Создаем модель, скажем в приложении `aclapp`:

```
class ACL(models.Model):
  model_content_type = models.ForeignKey(
       ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  object_id = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  username = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Запись в ACL будет означать, что пользователь `username` имеет доступ к объекту с идентификатором `object_id` типа описываемого `model_content_type`.

Теперь нужно модифицировать менеджер, чтоб он учитывал эту таблицу в запросах:

```
class AclAwareManager(models.Manager):
    def __init__(self, username, model):
       self.username = username
       self.content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(model)
       self.model = model
       self.name = 'acl_aware_for_{}'.format(username)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(id__in=_get_acl_filter())

    def _get_acl_filter(self)
        return RawSQL("select object_id from aclapp_acl where username = %s and model_conent_type = %s",
            (self.username, self.content_type.id,))
```

И использовать в модели:

```
class Client(models.Model):

   name = models.CharField(...)
   ...

   def accessible_objects(self, user):
      return AclAwareManager(user.usename, Client)
```

Ну и теперь можно использовать менеджер например во view:

```
def clients_view(request):
   clients = Client.accessible_objects(request.user).filter(name='some name')
```

В `clients` будет `queryset` аналогичный `Client.objects.filter(name='имя')`, только уже отфильтованный по таблице `acl`. Т.е. его нужно использовать, как список объектов типа `Client`.

На практике вместо `username` обычно хранят группу, и смотрят на вхождение пользователя в группу. Так же обычно создают по ACL записи на разный вид действия - т.е. одна запись описывет, кто может читать, вторая - кто может модифицирвать и т.д.

Comment: А почему не используется `contenttypes` ?

Comment: Получаю ошибку 'AclAwareManager' object has no attribute 'model'. models.py https://pastebin.com/5LjM35gf

Comment: Спасибо, Это помогло. Но теперь появляется новая ошибка 'AclAwareManager' object has no attribute 'name'

Comment: в views.py в переменной clients содержится "guiapp.client_config.acl_aware_for_root"  А как я понимаю, на выходе мы должны получать object_id клиента?

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я добился того, что хотел. Как мне корректнее выложить готовый результат?

Comment: Не знаю точно. Думаю, если изменения небольшие и есть права править ответ, то можно предложить правку к этому ответу. Иначе стоит создать новый ответ.

Answer (score 1):

чтобы получить текущего пользователя, достаточно взять его из `request.user` . передавать `id` на страницу списка пользователей, доступных для отображения смысла нет. Надо отталкиваться от `request.user`

Права на клиентов создаете сами, либо через `Meta` ( https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/options/#permissions ), либо ручками.

Исходя из этих прав, на странице отображения списка пользователей, фильтруете  `queryset` клиентов в зависимости от доступных прав

Нужно больше подробностей? Предоставьте больше информации (где, в админке или нет, как идет разграчением доступа к клиентам)

Answer (score -1):

Для начала, как я понял - надо вывести список клиентов, а потом детальное отображение каждого клиента? 2 функции (или класса) со списком клиентов и их детальном отображении. Соответственно, в первой view (список) - будет примерно такой запрос: Model.objects.all() - вывод всех клиентов. Потом детальное отображение: в создании пути, естественно нужен url-параметр, ну у вас это, что угодно, но в качестве примера пусть будет pk - `path('list_users/<int:user_id>/',detail,name='detail')`. Ну и во view:

```
def detail(request,user_id):
    user = Model.objects.get(id=user_id)
    ...
```

Ну и еще нужна проверка доступа. Ну здесь всё просто. К примеру в функции detail(детальное отображение клиентов) сделать проверку: `if request.user.`(тут пишите либо `is_staff` или `is_authenticated`, короче, что вам надо, то и пишите). Или воспользоваться функцией has_pemrs(туда передаете права, которыми должны обладать пользователи). Не знаю поможет ли вам это информация.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/auth/

Comment: Вы не поняли вопрос. `Model.objects.all()` - вернет всех, а нужно, что только тех, которые "доступны" текущему пользователю.

Comment: Ну тут уж даже не знаю. Как-то их фильтровать, но вот как составить условие для фильтрации я не знаю.